# Android: remove focus on EditText in PreferenceGroup

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, preferences

I have a form that when this form is submitted, I want to disable my textedit, would you please help me in this implementation,

Thanks in advance!

Here is part of my class that submitted button is:

```
public class MyForm extends PreferenceGroup implements View.OnClickListener {

if (isFormSubmited) {
            submitter.disable();

            FormField.buttonCatchButton.setText("View");
            updateForm();


        }
```

my button for disable the editTex

```
 private void disable(ViewGroup layout) {

    layout.setEnabled(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            disable((ViewGroup) child);
        } else {
            child.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
 }
```

my onclick method in another class

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        FormFragment formFragment = new FormFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants_Args.ITEMS_KEY, itemsKey);


        if (catchFormFile != null) {
            bundle.putString(Constants_Args.CATCH_FORM_FILE_PATH, catchFormFile.getAbsolutePath());

        }

        if (catchFormJSONObject != null) {
            bundle.putString(Constants_Args.CATCH_FORM_JSONOBJECT, catchFormJSONObject.toString());

        }

        if (catchSpeciesJSONArray != null) {
            bundle.putString(Constants_Args.CATCH_SPECIES_JSONARRAY, catchSpeciesJSONArray.toString());

        }

       catchFormFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getContext();
        mainActivity.pushFragment(formFragment);
    }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to set: If form submitted, formFragment needs to let its child views that the field is disabled

Comment: @shylendra Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: just go to xml file and right click on edit text and select  clear focus option by going to Graphical Layout.

Comment: @shylendra then it will be always clear focus but I just want to have it when I submit the form !!!